# How to update an element in Adapter list once changes have been made to the element in a different Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, adapter

I'm looking for the best implementation pattern in Android to update a list when one of the elements change in a different activity.

Imagine this user journey:

> An async process fetches ten (10) contact profiles from a web server. These are placed in an array and an adapter is notified. The ten (10) contact profiles are now displayed in a list.
>
> The user clicks on contact profile five (5). It opens up an activity with details of this contact profile. The user decides they like it and clicks 'add to favourite'. This triggers an async request to the web server that the user has favourited contact profile five (5).
>
> The user clicks back. They are now presented again with the list. The problem is the list is outdated now and doesn't show that profile five (5) is favourited.

Do you:

- Async call the web server for the updated data and notify the adapter to refresh the entire list. This seems inefficient as the call for the list can take a couple of seconds.
- On favouriting the profile store the object somewhere (perhaps in a singleton service) marked for 'refresh'. OnResume in the List activity do you sniff the variable and update just that element in the list.
- Ensure the list array is static available. Update the array from the detail activity. OnResume in the activity always notify the adapter for a refresh.
- Ensure the list array and adapter is static available. Update the array and notify the adapter from the detail activity.

Any other options? What is the best design principle for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Async call the web server for the updated data and notify the adapter
>   to refresh the entire list. This seems inefficient as the call for the
>   list can take a couple of seconds.

As you say, it's very inefficient. Creating an Object is expensive in Android. Creating a List of many object is much more expensive.

> On favouriting the profile store the object somewhere (perhaps in a
>   singleton service) marked for 'refresh'. OnResume in the List activity
>   do you sniff the variable and update just that element in the list.

This is not a good solution because there is a probability that the app crashes before we refresh the object or the app get killed by the device.

> Ensure the list array is static available. Update the array from the
>   detail activity. OnResume in the activity always notify the adapter
>   for a refresh.

Updating the array via a static method or variable is not a good solution because it makes your detail Activity get coupled with the list. Also, you can't make sure that only the detail activity that change the list if your project get bigger.

> Ensure the list array and adapter is static available. Update the
>   array and notify the adapter from the detail activity.

Same as the above, static variable or object is a no go.

---

You better use an Event Bus system like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Whenever you clicks `'add to favourite'` in detail activity, send the async request to update favourite to the web server and also send Event to the list activity to update the specific profile object. For example, if your profile has id "777" and the profile is favourited in detail activity then you need to send the Event something like this in your :

```
btnFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {               
     // Send event when click favourite.
     EventBus.getDefault.post(new RefreshProfileEvent(id, true);
   }
});
```

**RefreshProfileEvent** is a simple pojo:

```
public class RefreshProfileEvent {
  private String id;
  private boolean isFavourited;

  public RefreshProfileEvent(String id, boolean isFavourited) {
    this.id = id;
    this.isFavourited = isFavourited;
  }
  //getter and setter
}
```

Then you can receive the Event in your list activity to update the selected profile:

```
public class YourListActivity {
  ...
  @Override
  protected onCreate() {
    ...
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
  }

  @Override
  protected onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
  }

  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
  public void onMessageEvent(RefreshProfileEvent event) {
    // Refresh specific profile
    // For example, your profile is saved in List<Profile> mProfiles

    // Search for profile by its id.
    for(int i = 0; i < mProfiles.size(); i++) {
      if(mProfiles.getId().equals(event.getId()) {
        // Refresh the profile in the adapter.
        // I assume the adapter is RecyclerView adapter named mAdapter
        mProfiles.get(i).isFavourited(true);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
        // Stop searching.
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

You don't need to wait for AsyncTask request result returned by the server. Just make the profile favourited first and silently waiting for the result. If your request success, don't do anything. But if the request error, make the profile unfavourited and send unobstructive message like **SnackBar** to inform the user.

Comment: This is a really great in-depth answer. Thank you. I haven't heard or used EventBus before but I certainly will start using it from now on.

Comment: you're welcome. There is also RxJava, but I haven't use it before.

Answer (score 0):

Third option is the best when a user changes the data in detail activity the array should be changed and then when the use returns to main activity call Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

For an ArrayAdapter , notifyDataSetChanged only works if you use the add() , insert() , remove() , and clear() on the Adapter.

You can do something like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Refresh();
}

public void Refresh(){
     items = //response....
     CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,items);
           list.setAdapter(adapter);

       }
```

On every onResume activity it will refresh the list. Hope it helps you.